# Positive solution of pseudoinverse method

Tags: python, list, dataframe, numpy

I got solution using pseudoinverse method but some are negative solution. how to put condition to get all positive solution

```
R_pseudo = np.linalg.pinv(R)
result=R_pseudo.dot(L) 
result
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Isn't a pseudo-inverse unique? In that case, how would it allow more than one solution?

Comment: @Sujoypaul what do you mean by 'negative solution' please post a minimal reproducible example that contains the contents of the `R` matrix or that exhibits the same behavior. I'm guessing you want the elements of `R` to be non-negative but not clear and not able to diagnose the problem without a working example of `R` matrix.